# Meu software está a ser bloqueado pelo Windows Smartscreen

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

Estou a desenvolver um software e, ao testar o executável noutro computador deu-me esta mensagem do Windows Smartscreen.

Não sei do que se trata, já pesquisei e não encontrei nada que ajudasse.

[image: Screenshot da mensagem]

Do que se trata e como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Veja se ajuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8L7w0SGVgy4. Outra possibilidade é clicar com botão direito no executável, vai aparecer uma opção para não mostrar esta mensagem.

Comment: O problema é que é uma aplicação OP que será distribuída, não será só para um ou dois computadores...

Comment: Clique em "Mais Informações" e depois em "Executar mesmo assim".

Comment: Isso é um software que você desenvolveu?

Comment: Sim, é um software que eu estou a desenvolver

Comment: Sim, é um software que eu estou a desenvolver

Comment: acho que essa pergunta deveria ser migrada para o Super User - aqui em  http://superuser.com/

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira Não dá pra migrar para um site em Inglês. SOpt != SOen.

Comment: @utluiz verdade, tinha me esquecido desse detalhe, mas então como proceder já que essa pergunta foge do escopo do SOpt?

Answer (score 5):

O Windows Smartscreen [é o recurso de proteção do Microsoft Windows para aplicativos que não foram certificados pela Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/smartscreen-filter-faq#1TC=windows-7). A ideia normalmente é detectar aplicativos maliciosos que possam comprometer o funcionamento do seu Windows.

[O procedimento para submeter seu aplicativo para avaliação está aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/mt637086.aspx).